# Handling custom restrictions/exceptions in a bean class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, custom-data-type

I've created some custom bean classes for custom datatypes in my application such as `Address`, `PhoneNumber`, `SpecialCode`, etc.

These custom non-primitive *datatypes* has there own restrictions which I want to apply with them, for example think of a `PhoneNumber`:

```
public class PhoneNumber {
   private String stdCode;
   private String number;

   public PhoneNumber() {
   }

   public PhoneNumber(String stdCode, String number) {

      this.stdCode = stdCode;
      this.number = number;
   }

   /* getters and setters */

}
```

Now what makes me confused is the *restrictions* on a `PhoneNumber`, i.e., I want to make sure the `stdCode` must start with a `0`, or the `number` must be `7` or `8` digits long, etc.
So, where do apply these rules?
In the constructor? As:

```
//Custom costructor
public PhoneNumber(String stdCode, String number) {
    if (!stdCode.matches("[0-9]+") || !number.matches("[0-9]+")){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error in Parsing. The STD Code and Number MUST be numeric digits.");
    }
    if (!"0".equals(stdCode.substring(1, 2))){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The STD Code must begins with 0");
    }
    if (stdCode.length() < 3 || stdCode.length() > 5){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The STD Code must be 3 to 5 digits long. Current Number of digits: " + stdCode.length() + ". ");
    }
    this.stdCode = stdCode;
    this.number = number;
}
```

Or there can be *custom* exceptions also? And where should I merge those custom exceptions with my bean classes?
I am not an experienced programmer and would like to know about what design pattern should I apply here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create getters & setters for your phone # parts and do you validation checking in the setters

Comment: and what if I create a `phoneNumber` object through its constructor?

Comment: 1. its just my opinion, but i think non-default constructors should only be used for immutable objects where they are necessary. Otherwise, what you end up with is cascading constructor duplication hell every time you add a new variable to your class. Also, constructor parameters can be confusing

Comment: 2. If you must have a non-default constructor, have the constructor call the setter methods

Comment: +1 for your `2` point..and sorry but did not get the `1`, what I understand is when you are creating an object you must set its necessary values and default constructor could not do this, also, i don't have to call `setters`.

Comment: What I'm saying is that it is much more readable to use the default constructor and use setters to set all properties, rather than jamming everything into the constructor

Comment: then everytime i have to write, `phone = new PhoneNumber(); phone.setStdCode(code); phone.setNumber(number);` rather then just: `phone = new PhoneNumber(code, number);` ?? I think the 2nd one was more readable, thats why i like your idea of having `setters` in constructor

Comment: But in fact it is not as clear. What would happen in your example if you mixed up the parameters in the PhoneNumber constructor new PhoneNumber(number,code); this would probably look fine, but it would be a bug. When you do this using setters, it is clear what you are setting and what is being set.

Answer (score 1):

You can veto an update to a property by throwing a PropertyVetoException. See here for an example and explanation: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/malenkov/archive/2007/11/how_to_veto_a_p.html

Comment: this seem somewhere "hmmmm" for me.. :) will study out and reply..:)

Answer (score 1):

Its always better to validate the input during the time of its entry. Using Getter and Setter is a good option. So during the assignment of the data to the instance variable, its type and other parameters can be checked.

Comment: I personally do not like the idea of checking values in `setters` but if its the only solution i must stick to it, and as said by @ControlAltDel, i should have to use `setters` in constructor also in place of assignment expressions.

Comment: when you are using the private instance variables, u will have to use public getter and setters...that is where encapsulation plays its role in OOPs